# I want to store the back up of database in last 10 days with seperate folder

Tags: linux, shell

Following shell script for storing back up of laste 10 database.
but there is small problem.
the script create *.zip file of each data base with date and time and stored in backup folder.
so if i have 4 data base so it will create 4 zip file. And for laste 10 days back up, that mean total i have 40 data base back up.

I want to store the back up of database in last 10 days with seperate folder. so that each folder contain the back up of database.

Following is the shell script.

```
MHOST=localhost
MUSER=backup
MPASS=SECRET
BACKUPDIR="/mnt/backup"

MYSQL="$(which mysql)"
MYSQLDUMP="$(which mysqldump)"
GZIP="$(which gzip)"

DBPREFIX="$(hostname -s).mysqldb"

echo "Run MySQL backup"
DBS="$($MYSQL -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS -Bse 'show databases')"
for db in $DBS
do
    FILE=${BACKUPDIR}/${DBPREFIX}.${db}.`date +%Y%m%d`.gz
    $MYSQLDUMP --no-tablespaces --skip-lock-tables -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS $db | $GZIP -9 > $FILE
done 

find  -name "${BACKUPDIR}/${DBPREFIX}*" -type f -mtime +10 -exec rm -f '{}' ';'
```

I am new to the Linux environment.

Please help me on the same

Best Regards
Arvind Porlekar

Comment: That script does not create zip archives. It creates gzip compressed files. That is something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MHOST=localhost
MUSER=backup
MPASS=SECRET
BACKUPDIR="/mnt/backup"

MYSQL="$(which mysql)"
MYSQLDUMP="$(which mysqldump)"
GZIP="$(which gzip)"

DBPREFIX="$(hostname -s).mysqldb"

# changed
DATE_FOR_FOLDER=`date +%y%m%d`
makedir -p "$BACKUPDIR/$DATE_FOR_FOLDER"

echo "Run MySQL backup"
DBS="$($MYSQL -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS -Bse 'show databases')"
for db in $DBS
do
    # changed
    FILE=${BACKUPDIR}/${DATE_FOR_FOLDER}/${DBPREFIX}.${db}.`date +%Y%m%d`.gz
    $MYSQLDUMP --no-tablespaces --skip-lock-tables -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS $db | $GZIP -9 > $FILE
done 

# changed
find  -name "${BACKUPDIR}" -type d -mtime +10 -exec rm -rf '{}' ';'
```